# PHP substr() not working when 3rd parem is string like 0xe84?

Tags: php, regex, hex, substr

I'm having problems using `substr()` with matches coming from a regular expression (using `preg_match()` - `$a` contains the array of matches).

When echo'ing `a[1]` it equals `0xe84` and is a string (as I've checked using `gettype()`).

```
substr($file, $a[2], $a[1]); //not working...
```

**But if I do (Also note I can't actually do this as the third parem is generic coming from a regex - this is just used to illustrate my problem):**

```
substr($file, $a[2], 0xe84); //works fine - when entering the match directly as an integer
```

So my question is why does `substr()` work only when the 3rd parem is of an integer type, and how can I make `$a[1]` an integer so it works fine?

I've tried doing type casting (using `(int)`), using `intval()` as well as `settype(integer)` on `$a[1]`, however `$a[1]` then becomes `0` (and the `substr()` won't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'0xe84'` is a hex string, which is 3716 in decimal. You can convert it to an integer using [`hexdec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php):

```
substr($file, $a[2], hexdec($a[1]));
```

The reason it works when you pass `0xe84` without quotes is because php correctly interprets hex literals. However, it does not understand it as a hex number when used as a string `'0xe84'`.

Comment: Great, works exactly how I wanted it!, just glad someone understood my question.

Answer (score 0):

For a safe code you can use the **intval** function to retrieve the integer value :

```
substr($file, $a[2], intval($a[1],16));
```

the second param of intval means the base, here we're using HEX

Regards
NiL